# Reduce the time of displaying progress bar in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-progressbar

I have problem with reducing the time of displaying progress bar in WebView. For underesting a add image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnZvE.jpg).

Where I can implement some thread of something to stop showing progress bar for one second, while my web running in WebView?

I tried implement thread before showing progress bar in onPageStarted, but it waiting for whole loading page, not only for loading progress bar.

We have very slow loading on web page, so we need showing to users one or two second loading page in webview without progressbar, after this time show "loading" progress bar.

If you have question, please ask me, we need quick respond to resolve this problem. I'm trying to find some solution, but nothing.

Thanks a lot!

There is my ChromeClien.class

```
public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
private ProgressListener mListener;

public MyWebChromeClient(ProgressListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
    mListener.onUpdateProgress(newProgress);
    super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
}
public interface ProgressListener {
    public void onUpdateProgress(int progressValue);
}}
```

There is MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private WebView webview;
ProgressDialog prDialog;
String cekani;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

    Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);

    if (isFirstRun) {
        //show start activity
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrvniSpusteni.class));

    }

    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();

    if(KontrolaInternetu.isInternetAvailable(MainActivity.this)) //Vrátí hodnotu TRUE, pokud je připojení k internetu k dispozici
    {
        webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //Nastavení webové stránky
        webview.loadUrl(getString(R.string.url_aplikace));
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        //Puštění JavaScriptu pro web
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        WebSettings ws = webview.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webview, true);
        }else {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        }

        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }
        });

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Enabling HTML5-Features");
                Method m1 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDomStorageEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
                m1.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

                Method m2 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDatabaseEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
                m2.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

                Method m3 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDatabasePath", new Class[]{String.class});
                m3.invoke(ws, "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/");

                Method m4 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCacheMaxSize", new Class[]{Long.TYPE});
                m4.invoke(ws, 1024*1024*8);

                Method m5 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCachePath", new Class[]{String.class});
                m5.invoke(ws, "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/cache/");

                Method m6 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCacheEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
                m6.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

                Log.d(TAG, "Enabled HTML5-Features");
            }
            catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Reflection fail", e);
            }
            catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Reflection fail", e);
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Reflection fail", e);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
    //Zobrazení AlertDialogu pokud není připojení k internetu
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (!isFinishing()){
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setTitle(getString(R.string.no_internet))
                            .setMessage(getString(R.string.internet))
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)

                            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    finish();
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }})
                            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.zrusit), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                }})
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


}

      //Při stisknutí tlačítka zpět se uživatel vrátí ve webview nazpět bez toho, aby aplikace spadla.
private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// Progress bar - zobrazí se tehdy, pokud čekám na načítání stránky
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {


        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        prDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        prDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        prDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.nacitani_webove_stranky));
        prDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if(prDialog!=null){
            prDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}

  //Při stisknutí tlačítka zpět se uživatel dostane zpět pouze ve webview
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(webview.canGoBack() == true){
                    webview.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.endsWith(".mp3")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "audio/*");
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    } else if (url.endsWith(".mp4") || url.endsWith(".3gp")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    } else {
    return true;
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hey bro, you don't necessarily need to implement threads for your
>   requirement. Firstly you can load the url in the webview and after a
>   particular time period you can start displaying progress bar. For
>   calling the progress bar after certain time period you can use
>   **Handler**.

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {


    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
     public void run() {

       //Do something after 100ms
       prDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
       prDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
       prDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.nacitani_webove_stranky));
       prDialog.show();

      }
     }, 100);

}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    if(prDialog!=null){
        prDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```